# CSS3 vs Canvas for text rotation

Tags: html, canvas, css

I have an idea in my mind for a simple technical demo. It will have a good amount, maybe up to 100, different text labels with varying rotations and Z-orders. Also, there will be constant animation so the size, rotation and position of the labels will change.

This could be done using CSS3 or Canvas as far I can tell. The CSS3 approach should be more accessible but are there any other real differences to consider?

Edit: I also need be able to place labels quite accurately with their centre point.

Answer (score 2):

Either should be fine. I'd start with making a CSS3 one and then make a Canvas one only if somehow unsatisfied. Some considerations:

- As of today text in the DOM looks a lot better than text on Canvas for a lot of browsers. Some browsers don't do subpixel rendering on Canvas text (While others do) making it something written in the same font in the DOM and in canvas look very different. For visual consistency, CSS3 is better right now.
- Ask yourself what you might want to do with this later, if anything. Turn it highly interactive? Increase the number of objects above 10,000? Then you'll want to do Canvas, in short because 10,000 DOM objects is a "bad thing".
- I'm not sure which one would be faster with merely 100 text labels. It shouldn't be hard to write up a quick test on your target platforms to see.
- The CSS one will probably be much faster to make.
- Canvas text gradients don't work on all mobile devices last I checked
- Canvas text rotation + scaling used to look AWFUL in Chrome and Opera. Chrome has it fixed since version 12, Opera still looks awful. You can check your target browsers here: http://simonsarris.com/misc/scaleText.html Opera sort of looks like [this](http://chromium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=2833897286992020829&name=Capture.PNG&token=4338399867cf7aa50d8f5fcfcd84cade&inline=1).

Answer (score 1):

while css3 would be the nicest solution, you should at least consider svg too.
see a live example : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/DhqEN/show/
p.s. : a big minus for canvas, because it does not have text selection